# Serializing an Array in WCF with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, arrays, wcf, serialization, protobuf-net

I am trying to serialize an array of my dataobjects through WCF with protobuf-net.

If I serialize the Array of my dataobjects manually, it works successfully:

```
var proto = Serializer.CreateFormatter<DataType[]>();
```

which is way faster and smaller than the ordinary binary xml `DataContractSerializer` - thats why I wanna use it!

The 'DataType' class is just an example - I have many of those. When the reponse of my service is just a single object, everything works just fine.

But when my service returns an Array of objects it seems it does not know what to do and uses the ordinary `DataContractSerializer`.

The ProtoBehavior is applied:

```
endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoEndpointBehavior());
```

My dataobject is more or less like that:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
[ProtoContract]
public class DataType
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "K")]
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    // many more to come
}
```

and that's basically my service:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IBaseDataObjectUpdate), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypesProvider))]
public interface IDataTypeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    DataType[] Load(Filter[] filter, Guid clientGuid);

    // some more
}
```

I could track it down to the `TryCreate` in the `XmlProtoSerializer`. The call:

```
int key = GetKey(model, ref type, out isList);
```

does not return a valid key, therefore no `XmlProtoSerializer` is created.

That explains the behavior, but what are my options here?

I found an old answer of Marc Gravell where he suggests the creation of an object which consists of the Array. But as it is from 2011 it might be outdated:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6270267/2243584

Or can I add the model to protobuf-net somehow manually? As mentioned above the manual serialization is working.

Any comment is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so far I have come up with 2 solutions.

1. Do not use Arrays! It works with any other collection. Which caused me to investigate and leaded to solution:
2. Support Arrays in protobuf-net

I have adapted the method `internal static Type GetListItemType(TypeModel model, Type listType)` in the TypeMode class as follows:

```
if (listType.IsArray)  // NEW
{
  if (listType.GetElementType() == typeof(byte))
    return null;
}
if (listType == model.MapType(typeof(string)) // || listType.IsArray // CHANGED!!!
  || !model.MapType(typeof(IEnumerable)).IsAssignableFrom(listType)) return null;
```

I think I did figure out why arrays are excluded. Because if you support byte[], you get some problems when finally sending the data to the wire. At least I got some Assert and exception in the encode factory when dealing with byte[].

As I have no idea on the side effects of solution Nr. 2 - I stick with solution Nr. 1.

Nevertheless I am quite keen on a comment from Marc - of course, everybody is welcome!